# warning.js?8a56:35 Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop use redux-saga

Tags: reactjs, redux-saga

I've got this error whenever I issued any actions with the editor.

```
warning.js?8a56:35 Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `forumCard` of type `object` supplied to `ForumCard`, expected `array`.
    in ForumCard (created by Connect(ForumCard))
    in Connect(ForumCard) (created by RouterContext)
    in div (created by View)
    in View (created by Navigation)
    in div (created by View)
    in View (created by Navigation)
    in MuiThemeProvider (created by Navigation)
    in Navigation (created by WithWidth)
    in EventListener (created by WithWidth)
    in WithWidth (created by Connect(WithWidth))
    in Connect(WithWidth) (created by Authentication)
    in Authentication (created by Connect(Authentication))
    in Connect(Authentication) (created by RouterContext)
    in RouterContext (created by Router)
    in Router
    in Provider
```

this is my component

```
import React, {Component, PropTypes} from 'react';
import autobind from 'class-autobind';
import {Table, Row, Cell} from 'react-responsive-table';
import {Link} from 'react-router';

import View from '../components/View';

import styles from './ForumCard-style';

export default class ForumCard extends Component {

  constructor() {
    super(...arguments);
    autobind(this);
    this.state = {
      dateUpdateTopic: new Date(),
      forumCardErrorAlertIsShown: false,
    };
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    this.props.onFetchForumCard();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Table style={styles.padding} material>
          <Row header key="row1">
            <Cell key="cell1"><Link to="/forum/topic-detail">Topik</Link></Cell>
            <Cell key="cell2">Penulis</Cell>
            <Cell key="cell3">Komentar</Cell>
            <Cell key="cell4">Favorit</Cell>
          </Row>
        </Table>
      </View>
    );
  }
    }

ForumCard.propTypes = {
  onFetchForumCard: PropTypes.func,
  forumCard: PropTypes.array,
};
```

it's my container

```
import {connect} from 'react-redux';

import ForumCard from '../components/ForumCard';

export function mapStateToProps(state) {
  let {forumCard} = state;
  return {
    forumCard,
  };
}

export function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    onFetchForumCard() {
      dispatch({type: 'FETCH_FORUM_CARD_REQUESTED'});
    },
  };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ForumCard);
```

Comment: ```ForumCard.propTypes``` declares forumCard to be an array instead of an object (assuming an object is the correct behavior), or figure out why connect isn't passing in an array as the prop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have specified the `propType` for `forumCard` to be an array whereas its type is coming to be an `object`. Make sure that `forumCard` is `array`. Or if you intend it be an object change the propType to be Object

```
ForumCard.propTypes = {
  onFetchForumCard: PropTypes.func,
  forumCard: PropTypes.object,
};
```

Comment: forumCard` of type `array` supplied to `ForumCard`, expected `object`

Comment: please check your reducer, I am sure there is an inconsitency